# Microsoft SQL Service Management Studio 2005 'Script XXX as CREATE To' problem

Tags: sql, ssms

When using the 'Script Index as CREATE To' to duplicate an index from one table to another table I am not able to run the script. Without editing the generated code I get an error. I get the same error when working with any 'Script XXX as CREATE To' generated code. Any comments/suggestions to solve this problem?

**ERROR:**

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Line 6: Incorrect syntax near '('.

**SCRIPT:**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IncidentStop_Note] ON [dbo].[IncidentStop_Note] 
(
    [IncidentStopID] ASC,
    [NoteID] ASC,
    [Active_Fl] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**EDIT:**

As from the answer from [Stuart Ainsworth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539549/microsoft-sql-service-management-studio-2005-script-xxx-as-create-to-problem/1539599#1539599) it turns out I am in SQL Server 2000 (80) Compatibility level. My question would slightly change to how can I duplicate something from one table to another while working in 2005 but having the compatibility level of 2000?

Comment: What happens if you press the "Parse" button (or hit CTRL+F5)?  Does it still report an error?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but is there any other code in your query window?  Are you sure you're only executing/parsing what you posted?

Comment: What you see is all that is being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the compatibility mode or server level set to for the destination database?  Is it SQL 2000 (or compatibility mode 80)?  If so, then the WITH option will not run; the syntax generated by the SQL 2005 Mgmt Studio is 2005 compliant (even if you issue it against a SQL 2000 server or 2000-compliant database).

Comment: It is set to SQL Server 2000 (80). Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do with it being 2000?

Comment: You can set the default scripting options to be SQL 2000 compliant (under tools.. Scripting... Script for Server Version), but Mgmt Studio doen't allow you to script-for-version-on-the-fly.

Comment: THANKS A BUNCH! I've had this problem for a while now and decided finally to ask the internet.