# Query works in SQL Server 2005 but syntax error for SQL Server 2000

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I am trying to execute this query but getting syntax error when it perfectly fines with SQL server 2005 and table is already there and am trying to create new table on a different server,

```
USE [myDataBase]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Tittle] [varchar](1024) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](8000) NOT NULL,
    [Table2ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Table3ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)



WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Error**

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 16 Line 16: Incorrect syntax near
>   '('.

**In above example, Line 16 is empty and am so confused.**

Comment: I have not worked on 2000 so I don't know the difference. But just remove Schema before **Table name** i.e. change [dbo].[myTable] to [myTable]

Comment: Try not to pay too much attention to the line numbers given to you. its not like VS 2010 where it will pinpoint the exact line, think of them as more a general guide lol

Comment: @DevN00B If running the query in SSMS then double clicking on the error message should generally take you to the offending line though. It is the 16th line in the batch (18th overall)

Comment: @RJ1990 that is wrong.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539549/microsoft-sql-service-management-studio-2005-script-xxx-as-create-to-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WITH` in SQL Server 2000 allows only `FillFactor` to be set. See the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Remove other options from the `WITH` clause.