# What is wrong with this SQL statement syntax? Msg 170, Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
USE [WORDDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [noun_minor]    Script Date: 07/03/2013 13:34:21 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [noun_minor] ON [dbo].[2013Words] 
(
        [NOUN_NO] ASC,
        [MIN_NO] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

I get the error below when parsing the query, SQL Server 2000:

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Line 7: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 doesn't support most of those `WITH` options.

Comment: Specifically, the last three. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258260(v=sql.80).aspx) - which you should always check first - shows `PAD_INDEX | 
        FILLFACTOR = fillfactor | 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY | 
        DROP_EXISTING | 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE | 
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539549/microsoft-sql-service-management-studio-2005-script-xxx-as-create-to-problem

Answer (score 3):

The Create Table options that are in the last set of parenthesis are from SQL Server 2005+ and are not compatible with SQ Server 2000.  Take that whole list out, including removing the parentheses and it should work.

Like this:

```
USE [WORDDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [noun_minor]    Script Date: 07/03/2013 13:34:21 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [noun_minor] ON [dbo].[2013Words] 
(
    [NOUN_NO] ASC,
    [MIN_NO] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Actually, most of them *are* compatible. If the script is in source control or anything, I'd leave the supported ones in, so that it remains documented what command you ran (as opposed to just accepting defaults).

Comment: @AaronBertrand  Oops, sorry, I wasn't in a position where I could check.  I had to do a post-and-run...